# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'refreshSells'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i want to add setInterval to be able to get new data from database without needing to refresh the page so i used useEffect,setInterval,useState to solve it,put intial state {refresh : false, refreshSells: null}
and there is switch when it on refresh = true and refreshSells= setinterval() but i got annoying warning
**React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'refreshSells'. Either include it or remove the dependency array**
and if i add refreshSells it will be unstoppable loop

```
const Sells = () => {
        const [allSells,setAllSells] = useState([])
        const [refresh,setRefresh] = useState(false)
        const [refreshSells , setRefreshSells] = useState(null)
        const [hidden,setHidden] = useState(true)
        useEffect(() => {
            Axios.get('/sells')
            .then(({data}) => {
                setAllSells(data.sells)
            })
            .catch(() => {
                alert('something went wrong,ask omar')
            })
        },[])
        useEffect(() => {
            if(refresh){
                setRefreshSells(setInterval(() => {
                    Axios.get('/sells')
                    .then(({data}) => {
                        setAllSells(data.sells)
                    })
                }, 60000));
            }
            else{
                clearInterval(refreshSells)
            }
            return () => clearInterval(refreshSells)
        },[refresh])
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `setRefreshSells` and `setRefresh`?? explain please

Comment: Without `useEffect` the interval won't be cleared on unmount and you'll get "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component"

Answer (score 0):

`setRefreshSells` updates internal state and doesn't change `refreshSells` during current render. So `return () => clearInterval(refreshSells)` will try to clear the wrong interval.

You should use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook for your interval:

```
const refreshSellsRef = useRef(null);
...
useEffect(() => {
    if(refresh){
        refreshSellsRef.current = setInterval(() => {
            Axios.get('/sells')
            .then(({data}) => {
                setAllSells(data.sells)
            })
        }, 60000);
        return () => clearInterval(refreshSellsRef.current);
    }
},[refresh])
```

Also note that `return () => clearInterval(refreshSellsRef.current)` will be called on unmount and when `refresh` changes. So you don't need `else {clearInterval(...)}`

Answer (score 0):

If your business logic allows to separate the 2 effects (automatic refresh every 60s + manual refresh after clicking some button), that would simplify the code for each independent effect:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            Axios.get('/sells')
            .then(({data}) => {
                setAllSells(data.sells)
            })
        }, 60000)
        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (refresh) {
            setRefresh(false)

            Axios.get('/sells')
            .then(({data}) => {
                setAllSells(data.sells)
            })
        };
    }, [refresh])
```

It looks like you forgot to `setRefresh(false)` after triggering the refresh, but I am not sure why you needed `refreshSells` in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

In the second `useEffect` you're updating the state `refreshSells` where `useEffect` expecting `useCallback` ref as a dependency. If you add `refreshSells` as a dependency to the `useEffect` then you may endup into memory leak issue.

So I suggest you try the below code which will solve your problem. by this you can also eliminate `refreshSells`

```
useEffect(() => {
    let interval;
    if (refresh) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
         Axios.get('/sells')
          .then(({ data }) => {
            setAllSells(data.sells)
          });
      }, 4000);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [refresh]);
```